# How to retrieve only arabic texts from a string using regular expression?

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, unicode

I have a string which has both Arabic and English sentences. What I want is to extract Arabic Sentences only.

```
my_string="""
What is the reason
ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
behind this?
ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
"""
```

[This Link](http://jrgraphix.net/r/Unicode/0600-06FF) shows that the Unicode range for Arabic letters is `0600-06FF`.

So, very basic attempt came to my mind is:

```
import re
print re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]+',my_string)
```

But, this fails miserably as it returns the following list.

```
['What', 'is', 'the', 'reason', 'behind', 'this?']
```

As you can see, this is exactly opposite of what I want. What I am missing here?

N.B.

I know I can match the Arabic letters by using inverse matching like below:

```
print re.findall(r'[^a-zA-Z\s0-9]+',my_string)
```

But, I don't want that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace ascii characters with empty string.

```
>>> my_string="""
... What is the reason
... ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
... behind this?
... ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
... """
>>> print(re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z?]', '', my_string).strip())
ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ

ذَلِكَ الْكِتَابُ لَا رَيْبَ فِيهِ هُدًى لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
```

Your regex didn't work because you are using Python 2 and your string is `str` you need to convert `my_string` to unicode for it to work. However it did perfectly work on Python3.x

```
>>> print "".join(re.findall(ur'[\u0600-\u06FF]', unicode(my_string, "utf-8"), re.UNICODE))
ذَلِكَالْكِتَابُلَارَيْبَفِيهِهُدًىلِلْمُتَّقِينَذَلِكَالْكِتَابُلَارَيْبَفِيهِهُدًىلِلْمُتَّقِينَ
```

Comment: Thanks  for your nice answer, +1 But why the above attempt don't work?

Comment: I am Satisfied :)  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Your code is:

```
print re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]+',my_string)
```

When matching a byte sequence, there is no such concept as Unicode code points. Therefore, the `\u` escape sequences in the regular expression don’t make any sense. They are not interpreted as you thought, but just mean `u`.

So when parsing the regular expression for bytes, it is equivalent to:

```
print re.findall(r'[u0600-u06FF]+',my_string)
```

This character class is interpreted as “one of `u060`, or a byte in the range `0-u`, or one of `06FF`”. This, in turn, is equivalent to `[0-u]`, since all the other bytes are already included in this range.

```
print re.findall(r'[0-u]+', my_string)
```

Demonstration:

```
my_string = "What is thizz?"
print re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]+',my_string)
['What', 'is', 'thi', '?']
```

Note that the `zz` is not matched, since it comes behind `u` in the ASCII character set.

Comment: This is the best explanation of the situation. I wish I could do +2. Thanks mate :)

Comment: shouldn't this read:   “one of **u060**, or a byte in the range *0-u*, or one of *06FF*”

Comment: Thank you very much for your careful reading. I have fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Your original code was correct, just needed to encode `my_string` with proper encoding, 'utf-8' and add `u` in your `re` pattern since you are working with Python2,

```
>>> for x in re.findall(ur'[\u0600-\u06FF]+', my_string.decode('utf-8')):
        print x


ذَلِكَ
الْكِتَابُ
لَا
رَيْبَ
فِيهِ
هُدًى
لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
ذَلِكَ
الْكِتَابُ
لَا
رَيْبَ
فِيهِ
هُدًى
لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
```

This will give you a list of matched unicode strings instead of single characters that you don't need to join them back with `''.join`

If you were in Python3, you don't need any of encoding tweeking as default encoding is 'utf-8':

```
>>> for x in re.findall(r'[\u0600-\u06FF]+', my_string):
        print(x)


ذَلِكَ
الْكِتَابُ
لَا
رَيْبَ
فِيهِ
هُدًى
لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
ذَلِكَ
الْكِتَابُ
لَا
رَيْبَ
فِيهِ
هُدًى
لِلْمُتَّقِينَ
```