# How do I get this regular expression to ignore accented characters?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file that my script is reading and getting the most frequent words from. However, at one point in the process of doing that, during the clean-up of the source text, it cannot handle accented characters (in this case, they are áéíóöőúüű).

This is what I have at the moment.

```
str = re.sub(r'\W+', ' ', str)
```

This simply deletes the accented characters. I have tried adding `flags=re.U`, but it just messed up the result in a different way. I suspect there is a simple way to solve my problem and I have looked for it, but haven't been successful and so I turn to you. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: @DSLima90 2.7.10

Comment: not a cleaning solution, but I've been tasked with a similar job.  You can convert those characters to their logical standard ascii with unidecode.unidecode(text).  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode  That might be even better than stripping them.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36661837/how-to-retrieve-only-arabic-texts-from-a-string-using-regular-expression

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @samuset: One note: `str` is not a good name for a variable in Python. Use `s`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew got it, I realize why, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the right modifier:

```
str = re.sub(ur'\W+', u' ', s, flags=re.UNICODE)
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

See [Python 2.x docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE):

> Make the `\w`, `\W`, `\b`, `\B`, `\d`, `\D`, `\s` and `\S` sequences dependent on the Unicode character properties database. Also enables non-ASCII matching for [IGNORECASE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.IGNORECASE).

Here is an online [Python 2.7 demo](https://ideone.com/dHhczU):

```
import re
s = u"characters (in this case, they are áéíóöőúüű)."
res = re.sub(ur'\W+', u' ', s, flags=re.UNICODE).encode("utf8")
print(res) # => characters in this case they are áéíóöőúüű
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried that and that does solve the problem with the accents, but then it doesn't seem to remove other non-alphabetical characters, such as punctuation.

Comment: @samuset if you just want alphabet chars, use `str.isalpha()`

Comment: @samuset: Have a look at [this demo](https://ideone.com/iAqnLN). It removes all non-word chars taking into account all Unicode letters. And removes punctuation, too.

Comment: @Chris_Rands that checks whether str is alpha or not, but can I use it to "clean" the string?

Comment: `\W` is more than `isalpha`, as `\W` matches any char that is not a Unicode letter, digit or `_`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works indeed, thank you very much.